# Using a different contour with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{x^m}{1+x^n}\, dx}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$I(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{x^m}{1+x^n}\, dx}$$
Usually a wedge contour with angle $\frac{\pi}{2n}$ would be used to only have one pole in the contour, but I think this can also be computed by using the entire semicircle in the upper half plane. I was trying to compute the residues in terms of $n$ and $m$, given that the poles are at $\frac{\pi}{n}(2k+1)$ :

$$\begin{align}\mathrm{Res(I)}&=\lim_{z\to e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}(2k+1)}}\frac{z^m}{1+z^n}\\&=\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi m}{2}(2k+1)}}{n(e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}(2k+1)})^{n-1}}\\&=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}(2k+1)(m+1)}}{e^{i\pi(2k+1)}}\right)\\&=-\frac{1}{n}e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}(2k+1)(m+1)}\end{align}$$

Then summing and multiplying by $2\pi i$,

$$\begin{align}{-\frac{2\pi i}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}(2k+1)(m+1)}}}&=-\frac{2\pi i}{n}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}(m+1)}(1-e^{i\pi n(m+1)})}{1-e^{i\pi(m+1)}}\right)\\&=-\frac{2\pi i}{n}\left(\frac{1-e^{i\pi n(m+1)}}{-2i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}(m+1))}\right)\end{align}$$

After cancelling, I’m not sure how to continue this though (mainly I’m struggling to simplify the exponential in the numerator without introducing more issues)

Comment: Are we assuming $n$ and $m$ are even with $m < n$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog, sorry for the late replay but yes, we are. I don't think it converges (specifically the arc)